# Calculator using recursion

Tags: c#

This is my code and i'm trying to do a  basic calculator. Theres just one textbox where i'll be writing two numbers and adding them as well as getting the result in the same textbox like most calculators do.
my problem is that i get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

after i press button + to write the next number.

```
public class calculator
{
    int acum = 0;
    int calcule(int option, int number)
    {
        switch (option)
        {
            case 3:
                acum = acum + number;
                break;
            case 4:
                acum = acum - number;
                break;
            case 5:
                acum = acum * number;
                break;
            case 6:
                acum = acum / number;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (number == 0)
        {
            return acum;
        }
        else
        {
            return calculate(option, number);
        }
    }
}

private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numero1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtnumber.Text);

    calculadora calcular = new calculadora();

    txtnumber.Text = calculator.calculate(btnadd.TabIndex, number).ToString();
}

private void btnminus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numero1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtnumber.Text);

    calculadora calcular = new calculadora();

    txtnumber.Text = calculator.calculate(btnminus.TabIndex, number).ToString();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(txtnumber.Text);

    calculadora calcular = new calculadora();

    txtnumber.Text = calculator.calculate(button1.TabIndex, number).ToString();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numero1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtnumber.Text);

    calculadora calcular = new calculadora();

    txtnumber.Text = calculator.calculate(button2.TabIndex, number).ToString();
}
```

Comment: If you don't ever change `option` or `number`, and then call the function again, how do you expect to exit the recursion?

Comment: As @RonBeyer said before, unless the input to calculate is 0 you will always end up calling calculate in an infinite recursion, your end condition is invalid, and may also lead to a divide by zero error

Comment: What Ron Beyer said, don't recurse with the same inputs. I'm intrigued by the purpose of this contraption. Quick suggestions, `calcule` doesn't look like it should be shared code, or at least not in it's current state. Switch statements like this are warning bells for poor design. Using number codes `case 6` to represent meaning is also a bit fishy, this is why Enums exist (I'm typing this and i can't remember what 6 was, dividing? :D Yep, good guess nathan).

Comment: I was thinking of placing an = button that would stop recursion when doing a click on it because it would pass a 0 value though tabindex in order to accomplish this but it doesn't matter because this happens when click button add.

Comment: Thanks @NathanCooper, I'll work on my coding design as you said.

Comment: @NathanCooper Calcule is wrong, the correct form is calculate and it is public int calculate()...my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is many problems in your code:

1. acum is not static, each time you do Calculator calc = new Calculator(); the value is set to zero. So even if there was no error in your code, the result would be number.
2. The value of the arg number never changes in Calculate method so there is no way you can escape the recursive call once you enter the else here (=> StackOverflowException)

   `if (number == 0)
       {
           return acum;
       }
   else
       {
           return calculate(option, number);
       }`
3. And also Calculate(...) is private... you cannot access it outside the class Calculator

Try this :

    `enum OperationEnum
    {
        ADD=3,
        SUB=4,
        MUL=5,
        DIV=6
    }
    public class Calculator
    {
        public double Calculate(OperationEnum operation, params int[] operands)
        {
            if (operands == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            if (operands.Length == 0)
                    return 0;
            if (operands.Length == 1)
                return operands[0];
            switch (operation)
            {
                case OperationEnum.ADD:
                    return Add(operands);
                case OperationEnum.SUB:
                    return Subtract(operands);
                case OperationEnum.MUL:
                    return Multiply(operands);
                case OperationEnum.DIV:
                    return Divide(operands);
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("operation");
            }
        }
        private double Divide(int[] operands)
        {
            if (operands.Length == 0)
                return 0;
            var result = operands[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < operands.Length; i++)
            {
                double divider = operands[i];
                if (divider == 0)
                {
                    throw new DivideByZeroException();
                }
                result /= divider;
            }
            return result;
        }
        private double Multiply(int[] operands)
        {
            if (operands.Length == 0)
                return 0;
            double result = operands[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < operands.Length; i++)
            {
                result *= operands[i];
            }
            return result;
        }
        private double Subtract(int[] operands)
        {
            if (operands.Length == 0)
                return 0;
            var result = operands[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < operands.Length; i++)
            {
                result -= operands[i];
            }
            return result;
        }
        private int Add(int[] operands)
        {
            return operands.Sum();
        }
    }
    private double _accumulator = 0;
    private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numero1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtnumber.Text);
        Calculator calcular = new Calculator();
        _accumulator = calcular.Calculate(OperationEnum.ADD,_accumulator, number);
        txtnumber.Text = _accumulator.ToString()
    }`

Comment: Thank you. @LeMara you gave me another perception of how to do things. I just wanted to make my code work with recursion.

Comment: Yes. @LeMara i would give points but i can't since i don't have enough reputation points in order to do so. but thank you!

Comment: @Mario: Never mind for points. If my answer helped you, that's the most important. Anyway, you can set question as answered and accept my answer as solution